# Covert sql query into X++ in ax 2012r2

Tags: sql, axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2012-r2

How to convert sql query in x++.

```
Select sum(Lineamount) as 'Lineamount',sum(qty) as 'Qty' from
(Select top(20) SUM(Lineamount) as 'Lineamount',sum(qty) as 'Qty' from CUSTINVOICETRANS c join SALESTABLE s on c.SalesID= s.salesid
where s.SALESTYPE =3 and Datepart(YYYY,c.INVOICEDATE) =2014 
group by s.CUSTACCOUNT 
order by SUM(Lineamount) desc).
```

Answer (score 0):

If my interpretation is correct, then the SQL statement can be formulated as

> Calculate the sum of the LineAmount and Qty of the 20 sales orders (SalesType=3) with highest LineAmount for 1 customer on transactions from the year 2014.

There are several issues why this single statement cannot be converted into a single X++ statement.

1. `top(20)` has no X++ equivalent. Only the keywords `firstOnly`, `firstOnly10`, `firstOnly100` and `firstOnly1000` [exist](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa656402.aspx). A `while select` loop will have to be used.
2. The X++ syntax does not allow the use of functions on data fields in the `where` clause of a statement. So the function `year(Date _date)` cannot be used at that point. Adding a redundant field InvoiceYear and populating it with the year date part can resolve this.
3. The X++ syntax has no support for subqueries as in the `select ... from ( select ...)` construction. Usually temporary tables are used for this.

Some *pseudo code* for a possible (and slow) solution could look like this:

```
// loop all customers with sales orders
while select CustAccount from SalesTable
    group by CustAccount
    where SalesTable.SalesType == SalesType::Sales
{
    // reset sum variables
    lineAmountSum = 0;
    qtySum = 0;

    // loop all transactions for the customer
    while select LineAmount, Qty, InvoiceDate from CustInvoiceTrans
        exists join SalesTable2
            where SalesTable2.SalesId == CustInvoiceTrans.SalesId
               && SalesTable2.CustAccount == SalesTable.CustAccount
    {
         // calculate the sum of all 2014 transactions
         if (year(CustInvoiceTrans.InvoiceDate) == 2014)
         {
             lineAmountSum += CustInvoiceTrans.LineAmount;
             qtySum += CustInvoiceTrans.Qty;
         }
    }

    // check if lineAmountSum beats a member of the current top 20
    if (lineAmountSum > lowestTop20LineAmountSum)
    {
        // remove lowest from top 20
        select firstOnly tmpLineAmountSumTop20
            where tmpSumTop20.LineAmountSum == lowestTop20LineAmountSum;
        tmpLineAmountSumTop20.delete();

         // add new top 20 member
         tmpLineAmountSumTop20.LineAmountSum = lineAmountSum;
         tmpLineAmountSumTop20.QtySum = qtySum;
         tmpLineAmountSumTop20.insert();

         // update current lowest
         lowestTop20LineAmountSum = (select firstOnly tmpLineAmountSumTop20 order by LineAmountSum asc).LineAmountSum;
    }
}

// calculate sum of top 20
select sum(LineAmountSum), sum(QtySum) from tmpSumTop20;
```